# Fully Qualified name of a python module

Tags: python, json, python-module

In the code-base I am working on, the default python `json` module is being overridden by another `json` module which performs a different function.

How do I import the standard `json` module ?

`import json` does not work as it imports the other package.

What is the fully qualified name of the standard python `json` module ?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. Better something like "import a standard library module even when it's name has been masked"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use absolute imports instead:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import json
```

You can still import the 'masking', local `json` module using the relative import syntax:

```
from . import json
```

Support for absolute imports as an option has been introduced in python 2.5, and is the default in python 3.

It'd be better to rename the 'masking' module, however.

Comment: `import .json` isn't valid syntax.  You need to do `from . import json`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Shows you how often I use it. Correcting.