# What is a qualified/unqualified name in Python?

Tags: python, fully-qualified-naming, qualified-name

In Python: what is a "qualified name" or "unqualified name"?

I've seen it [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697769/fully-qualified-name-of-a-python-module) a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020014/get-fully-qualified-class-name-of-an-object-in-python) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753227/importing-module-elements-in-another-with-no-qualified-name) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190238/how-to-get-the-qualified-name-of-the-currently-executing-function), but no explanation as to what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the path from top-level module down to the object itself.

See [PEP 3155, Qualified name for classes and functions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/).

If you have a nested package named `foo.bar.baz` with a class `Spam`, the method `ham` on that class will have a fully qualified name of `foo.bar.baz.Spam.ham`. `ham` is the unqualified name.

A qualified name lets you re-import the exact same object, provided it is not an object that is private to a local (function) namespace.

Comment: Are objects the only thing that have qualified names? Or can classes also have them? (Or is a class an object as well?)

Comment: Does a module have a qualified name?

Comment: And what is the difference (if any) between a qualified name and a fully qualified name?

Comment: Classes are objects; modules (objects too!) have a qualified name, that is what you use when you use an absolute import. Qualified names are not as formal as you think they are; the terms are not that ridgidly defined.